# kibana plugin : Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: kbnIndexProvider <- kbnIndex <- config

Tags: angularjs, plugins, kibana-4

im creating a custom plugin for kibana.

i have this message when i access to the url plugin i have this message

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: kbnIndexProvider <- kbnIndex <- config
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=kbnIndexProvider%20%3C-%20kbnIndex%20%3C-%20config (http://localhost:5601/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=8467:31723)
Version: 4.5.0
Build: 8467
Error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: kbnIndexProvider <- kbnIndex <- config
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=kbnIndexProvider%20%3C-%20kbnIndex%20%3C-%20config (http://localhost:5601/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=8467:31723)
at window.onerror (http://localhost:5601/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=8467:64992:25)
```

information :

```
kibana version : 4.5
plugin type : app
```

Cordially

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: yes with 5.0 version from kibana github